# Creating arrays in QTP

Tags: arrays, vba, if-statement, qtp

I am trying to create an array of integers in QTP ( the ints are 9, 16, 25,34,43). I think the code to instantiate it should be (but I could be wrong since I have never created an array in QTP before),

```
Dim pages(5)
pages(0) = 9
pages(1) = 16
...
```

Then I have a for loop with a variable that goes from 1 to 50 and based off of the value of the variable it does one thing and if the variable is one of the values in the array it does something else. For that I have,

```
For g = 1 to 50
   if g<> 9 and g<> 16 and g<> 25 and g<>34 and g<> 43 Then
     DoCoolStuff...
   else
     DoBoringStuff...
   End If
Next
```

My question is, is there a command that will allow me to replace that ugly if statement with something like 
if g <> in pages*?

Comment: There is no `in` operator like that you've outlined in VBA. You can, however, initialize a flag, do a `For`-`Each` loop (which does indeed use the 'in' keyword) to iterate over the elements of `pages`, and set a flag (and exit the loop) if `g` equals the current `page` element. After the loop, the flag tells you if you saw one of the `g` values in the inner loop in `pages`, thus you'd branch depending on the flag and do `DoCoolStuff` or `DoBoringStuff`. Let me know if that helps, or if you need an answer showing just that in code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Dimensioned Array, then that is the only way to declare an array. If you wanted a Non dimensioned array you then can use,

```
Dim pages()
pages = Array(9, 16, 25, 34, 43)
```

However, you can also do this,

```
Dim pages()
ReDim pages(5)
pages = Array(9, 16, 25, 34, 43)
```

Coming to your problem, you can get this going by using the Filter function. Although there is a very small problem. [Filter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-Function-41ba40b0-d058-4c76-91e5-a2d30a1ae45b) method takes in String, so even with that function your will match 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 along with the real/actual values 9, 16, 25, 34, 43.

As,

- 1 occurs in 16.
- 2 occurs in 25.
- 3 occurs in 34 and 43.
- 4occurs in 34 and 43.
- 5 occurs in 25.
- 6 occurs in 16.

It still thinks they occur in the String. One way to get around this is to Format the numbers as a two literal. Something like.

```
Dim pages(), g As Integer

ReDim pages(5)
pages = Array("09", "16", "25", "34", "43")

For g = 1 To 50
    If UBound(Filter(pages, Format(g, "00"))) > -1 Then
        'Do Cool Stuff here
    Else
        'Do Boring Stuff here
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT :**

The other way is to create a User Defined Function that could Loop through your Array and find if the Value is Found in your Array. Something like,

```
Public Function FindArrayElement(SearchArray As Variant, LookupValue As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim aCtr As Integer

    For aCtr = 0 To UBound(SearchArray)
        If CLng(SearchArray(aCtr)) = LookupValue Then
            FindArrayElement = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    FindArrayElement = False
End Function
```

The function takes in two Arguments. The first is the Array in which the values are defined, the second is the Value looked up for. So your Original code would change to.

```
Dim pages(), g As Integer

ReDim pages(5)
pages = Array(9, 16, 25, 34, 43)

For g = 1 To 50
    If FindArrayElement(pages, g) Then
        'Do Cool Stuff here
    Else
        'Do Boring Stuff here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What I don't like about this suggestion is that it is based on string comparions, while the task is to compare numerical values. But +1 because the array assignment is a good thing.

Comment: @TheBlastOne, thank you. I was about to suggest a UDF, which could work the same way, although it works a little bit complicated. For every Loop a UDF has to be called, which will in-turn run a For loop. However, I will still add it to my answer.

Comment: You are welcome ! Please mark it as answer if you found it useful, so others might benefit from it too.

Answer (score 1):

First, I, too, would suggest to initialize `Pages` like this:

```
Dim Pages(): Pages=(9,16,25,34,43)
```

Second, and independently from the first aspect, you could use this code to check if `g` is contained in `Pages`:

```
Dim Elem
Dim Found: Found=false
For Each Elem in Pages
    If Elem = g then
        Found=true
        Exit For
    End If
End For
If Found then
    DoBoringStuff
else
    DoCoolStuff
End If
```

The `For`..`Each` loop iterates as many times as there are elements in the `Pages` array. For each iteration, `Elem` is set to one `Pages` array element.

Note that the comparison is between Integers, as requested.